# Possible to rename files so they pass through multiple loaders in Webpack?

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

I currently have some loaders like this:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            use: 'babel-loader',
        },
        {
            test: /\.(ts|tsx)?$/,
            use: [
                {loader: 'babel-loader'},
                {loader: 'ts-loader'},
            ],
        },
    ],
},
```

But, as you see, I have babel-loader listed twice. Is it possible to somehow add a renaming step so that I can remove the `babel-loader` from the `.ts` files, so after they pass through ts-loader they will be renamed to `.js` and then be handled by `babel-loader` for `.js` files?

For example, if I remove babel-loader from the `.ts` section:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        {
            test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
            use: 'babel-loader',
        },
        {
            test: /\.(ts|tsx)?$/,
            use: 'ts-loader',
        },
    ],
},
```

Is there some other config I can add so that ts files are named to js files and then subsequently pass through babel-loader?

Comment: Why not to expand `test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,` to `test: /\.(js|jsx|ts|tsx)$/,`? Then it will process through ts-loader first and babel-loader after avoiding the need for renaming.

Comment: @JuhoVepsäläinen Because then ts-loader is running on files it doesn't need to run on.

Comment: But that wouldn't change the ts-loader specific definition. It would be functionally equivalent to your first example thanks to matching and evaluating order. I'm probably missing some obvious precondition here...

Comment: Webpack doesn't allow renaming. You would have to PR that if you want to go with that thinking instead.